# Fixing/hiding Path Based Vulnerabilities in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, security, qualys

I have a WordPress site that I manage. I recently received a Qualys vulnerability security scan (non-authenticated scan) that has a large number of "Path Based Vulnerability" findings. Almost all of the paths listed follow this format:

> https://www.example.com/search/SomeString

> https://www.example.com/search/1/feed/rss2

Some examples include:

> https://www.example.com/search/errors

> https://www.example.com/search/admin
> https://www.example.com/search/bin

When I go to these URL's, I get an appropriate search page response stating, for example, "Search for Admin produced no results".

But, if I go to https://www.example.com/search/ without a string parameter, I get a 404 error (custom error page) stating the page could not be found. All this works like I would expect it to.  No sensitive data/pages are being shown.

An example of the Qualys finding is:

> 150004 Path-Based Vulnerability URL:
> https://www.example.com/search/1/feed/rss2/ Finding #
> 8346060(130736429) Severity Confirmed Vulnerability - Level 2 Unique #
> redacted Group Path Disclosure Detection Date 22 Mar 2021 18:16
> GMT-0400 CWE CWE-22 OWASP A5 Broken Access Control WASC WASC-15
> APPLICATION MISCONFIGURATION WASC-16 DIRECTORY INDEXING WASC-17
> IMPROPER FILESYSTEM PERMISSIONS CVSS V3 Base 5.3 CVSS V3 Temporal5
> CVSS V3 Attack VectorNetwork
>
> **Details**
> **Threat** A potentially sensitive file, directory, or directory listing was discovered on the Web server.
>
> **Impact** The contents of this file or directory may disclose sensitive information.
>
> **Solution** Verify that access to this file or directory is permitted. If necessary, remove it or apply access controls to it.
>
> **Detection Information**
> **Parameter** No param has been required for detecting the information.
> **Authentication** In order to detect this vulnerability, no authentication has been required.
> **Access Path** Here is the path followed by the scanner to reach the exploitable URL: https://www.example.com
> https://www.example.com/?s=1
>
> **Payloads**
>
> ```
> #1
> #1 Request
> GET https://www.example.com/search/tools/
> Referer: https://www.example.com
> Cookie: [removed in case its sensitive];
> caosLocalGa= [removed in case its sensitive];
> Host: https://www.example.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1
> ```
>
> Safari/605.1.15
> Accept: */*

Based on the findings, this seems to be a false positive.  But, my CIO insists that I prove it as such.  First, is there any documentations on this that might be helpful?  Second, does anyone know of any updates to WP that could hide/remove these findings?

Answer (score 0):

(I'd comment, but my rep isn't high enough.)

I can partially answer this, as I fighting the same battle right now with a different web app. If you run the request in a browser with the developer tools on, I'll bet you'll see the response code from the server is 200 even though it is actually doing a redirect.

The scanner sees the response code is OK and based on that, the request succeeded as is when it really didn't. You have to give it a different response code when doing a "silent" redirect.